# How can I find the unused disk with Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to scan the node and use the information to create the file system on all unused disks with a Chef recipe.

I tried checking the output of Ohai and I wanted to know if anyone has used the Ohai information to find the unused disk.

UUID is something I tried to check as well.

Comment: Grammatical fixes

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compare the current mounts against the list of block devices. Ohai does have both of those lists, but you'll have to write the code to compare them and that could get complex given how Linux block device aliasing works (i.e. you might not be able to do this without also having access to the machine to resolve aliases).